# Fractions with denominator $41$ leading to a recurring decimal number with period $24390$

Tags: number-theory

Consider the fraction:

$\frac{A}{41}$ where A is a positive integer.

$\frac{18}{41}=0.4390\overline{24390}$

$\frac{69660}{41}=1699.0\overline{24390}$

$\frac{92020}{41}=2244.390\overline{24390}$

What are the values of A for which $\frac{A}{41}$ ends with the period $\overline{24390}$?

$24390=29^3+1$

Moreover $\frac{24390}{41*271*9}=0.\overline{24390}$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88422/discussion-on-question-by-virgilius-fractions-with-denominator-41-leading-to-a).

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {1}{41} = 0.\overline {02439}\\
\frac {10}{41} = 0.\overline {24390}\\
\frac {100}{41} = 2.\overline {43902}\\
\frac {100}{41} - 2 = \frac {18}{41} = 0.\overline {43902}$

The numerators are equivlatent to $10^n \pmod {41}$

Comment: ok so also A=69660, A=92020, A=541456, A=215 are equivalent to $10^n$ $\pmod {41}$?

Comment: $92020 - 2220\cdot 41 = 1000, 15 - 41\cdot 5 = 10$

Answer (score 0):

Bear with me.

$41*2439 = 99,999$ and so $10^5 \equiv 1 \pmod {41}$.

$1,10,10^2, 10^3, 10^4$ are equivalent $\mod 41$ to $1,10, 18,16,37$.

Claim:  If $x = a*41 + r$ where $r = 1,10,18,16,$ or $37$ then $\frac x{41}$ will have a repeating term $02439$.

If $x = a*41 + 1$ then $\frac x{41} = a + \frac 1{41}$ and will have the same repeating terms as $\frac 1{41}$.

Likewise with $x = a*41 + 10$ then $\frac x{41} = a + \frac {10}{41}$ will have the same repeating terms as $\frac {10}{41}$.

For $x = a*41 + 18 = (a-2)*41 + 100$ then $\frac x{41} = a-2 + \frac {100}{41}$ will have the same repeating terms as $\frac {100}{41}$

And by similar argument if $x = a*41 + 16 = b*41 + 1000$ and $x = a*41 + 37 = b*41 + 10^4$ we get the same repeating ters as $\frac {10^3}{41}$ and $\frac {10^4}{41}$

And as they are powers of ten they will all have the same repeating terms just begining at different points.

And $\frac 1{41} = 0.\overline {02439}$

Comment: ok thanks and so what about x=215, x=69660, x=92020 and x=541456?

Comment: and what about the period 24390? 24390=29^3+1 is there any explanation?

Comment: Well $215\equiv 10 \pmod {41}$ and $69660\equiv 1\pmod {41}$ and $541456 \equiv 10\pmod{41}$.

Comment: yes they are exponents multiples of 43 of my primes obtained concatenating base 10 two consecutive Mersenne numbers. Maybe the exponents are not random but follow some rule.

Comment: And $24390 = 29^3 + 1$ may be a coincidence.  But $29^3=(30-1)^3=3^3*10^3-3^3*10^2+3^2*10-1=3(10-1)10^3-3(10-1)10^2+(10-1)10-1$ and $(29^3+1)(41)=[3(10-1)10^3-3(10-1)10^2+(10-1)10-1][50-10+1]=...=1,000,000-10$ maybe shouldn't be that surprising.

Comment: "Maybe the exponents are not random but follow some rule." Well, $43 \equiv 2 \pmod {41}$.......

Comment: k=215, 69660, 92020, 541456 are multiples of 43 and (2^k-1)*10^d+2^(k-1)-1 where d is the number of decimal digits of 2^(k-1)-1, gives probable primes for k=215, 69660, 92020, 541456...all numbers of the form 41s+r...with r=1,10,16,18,37...i doubt that this is coincidence

Comment: Of course that's not a coincidence.  It's an immediate and direct result of everything we've all been answering.

Comment: I don't understand..you did not consider the primality of the number

Comment: i wonder why only when (2^k-1)*10^d+2^(k-1)-1 is prime and k is a multiple of 43, then k is of the form 41s+r?

Comment: in other words i wonder why when k is a multiple of 43 but not of the form 41s+r then (2^k-1)*10^d+2^(k-1)-1 is composite

Comment: to be prime (2^k-1)*10^d+2^(k-1)-1 with k multiple of 43 is it necessary that k is also of the form 41s+r?